# Going through a square matrix in an ever smaller spiral

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

What I want to do is an algorithm that goes through a matrix in a closing spiral pattern as follows:

```
1 | 2 | 3
---------
8 | 9 | 4
---------
7 | 6 | 5
```

What would be the simplest way to tackle this problem ?

My thoughts:

- Corner or obstacle detection.
- Have a programmatic way to go down vertically and in reverse.
- Have a way to detect that an element has already been visited.

P.S: Not sure how to handle a case where the size is not a square or the width is an even number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a visited concept for each cell, just a single variable to indicate how far you are.

Below is some (not extensively tested) Java code to do this.

It should be pretty readable.

```
  // initialize
  int w = 5, h = 7;
  int[][] arr = new int[w][h];

  // do the work
  int count = 1;
  for (int i = 0; count <= w*h; i++)
  {
     // go right
     for (int x = i; x < w-i && count <= w*h; x++)
        arr[x][i] = count++;

     // go down
     for (int y = i+1; y < h-i && count <= w*h; y++)
        arr[w-i-1][y] = count++;

     // go left
     for (int x = w-2-i; x >= i && count <= w*h; x--)
        arr[x][h-i-1] = count++;

     // go up
     for (int y = h-2-i; y > i && count <= w*h; y--)
        arr[i][y] = count++;
  }
```

[Java](https://ideone.com/K3TKdz).

Output:

```
  1  2  3  4  5
 20 21 22 23  6
 19 32 33 24  7
 18 31 34 25  8
 17 30 35 26  9
 16 29 28 27 10
 15 14 13 12 11
```

Answer (score 1):

For each cell, have a number that denotes how many empty/visited cells are in its immediate vertical and horizontal position (let's call it `numVisitedAroundCell`.) Also, have a boolean flag `isVisited`. Go through the cells and update `numVisitedAroundCell` (so the corner cells would have `numVisitedAroundCell == 2` and the outer layer of cells that is not a corner would have `numVisitedAroundCell == 1`)

Go through the cells and find a corner cell, which would be a cell with `numVisitedAroundCell == 2`.

From there, either go vertically or horizontally, while marking each cell you pass as `isVisited` and incrementing the number of `numVisitedAroundCell`.  Keep going down the path you choose until you hit a corner cell(when you hit this corner cell, `numVisitedAroundCell` should be 3), then find the next unvisited cell, and go down that route. If you keep doing this, I believe you will get the spiral that you wanted. Also, this should deal with cases where the width is even and if the size is not square.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively, for no good reason:

Use four functions, named `right()`, `down()`, `left()`, and `up()`.

The `right()` function counts along the top row of the matrix, and then
passes the remaining rows (all excluding the one it just filled in) to
`down()`.

The `down()` function counts down the right edge of the matrix, and then
passes the remaining columns to `left()`.

etc.

Recursion stops when a width or a height reaches zero.